# "Illegal starting char" error whenever opening MacVim

Tags: macos, vim, macvim

Whenever I start MacVim, through Finder or through Terminal, I receive the following error:

```
E575: viminfo: Illegal starting char in line: c/gui_mac.txt
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

I have reinstalled multiple times. I found the only `gui_mac.txt` on my System (as far as I know) here:

> Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/doc/gui_mac.txt

Its "Last Opened" date is August 15th, 2010, which is several months before I even installed my operating system. I didn't edit it!

I searched Google for the error in quotes, and I didn't receive a single result. The closest bit of info I've been able to find is [here](http://www.groupsrv.com/computers/about63467.html), and it isn't very useful.

What is going on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Darn it. The link I provided did provide the correct solution. I have never touched my `.viminfo` file, so I don't know how an escape character got in there.

In short:

**Deleting the contents of my `.viminfo` file resolved the issue.**